# Passing a scrapy HtmlResponse object to an external function

Tags: python, scrapy

Using the Scrapy library I want to pass the response from the parse function to a function in an external `.py` file.

So I have my scrapy spider:

```py
import scrapy
from myspider.utils import ExternalClass


class MySpider(scrapy.spiders):
  ...

  def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
    # https://www.example.com
    ExternalClass.external_function(response)
```

and my external class:

```py
class ExternalClass()
  def external_function(self, response)
    print(response.url)
    # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'url'
```

I think I may be failing at Python here. Now I realise the `ExternalClass` has no idea how to handle a `HtmlResponse` object and that is the likely cause of my error. How do I get the `ExternalClass` to handle the `HtmlResponse` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the `external_class` object at the class level so in order to access it you have to use `self` keyword which refers to the current class that is `MySpider` so proper way will be to use

```
self.external_class.external_function(response)
```

Or you can define the instance in the parse method. this will work too.

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
    external_class = ExternalClass()
    external_class.external_function(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've resolved my issue. By creating an instance of `ExternalClass` inside my `MySpider` class like so:

```py
import scrapy
from myspider.utils import ExternalClass


class MySpider(scrapy.spiders):
  ...

  # new instance
  external_class = ExternalClass()

  def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
    external_class.external_function(response)
```

and adding a constructor to ExternalClass:

```py
class ExternalClass()
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def external_function(self, response)
    print(response.url)
```

I can now pass my `HtmlResponse` object and access it's properties.

I'm unsure but I'm guessing this has something to do with passing a reference of `self` from my parent class to the instantiated `ExternalClass`. Though when I instantiate `ExternalClass` I don't explicitly pass `self` and I didn't think Python was implicit with `self`?